# I need help formatting inner join command in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my ERD for SQL Server: 
https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5832/23786188186_d6f1d93132_o.jpg

I need to find out which books are associated with each publisher.

```
USE BookStoreDB
SELECT ProductID
FROM Books
INNER JOIN [Publishers] PublisherID ON PublishersID = ProductID
```

I'm assuming I just didn't create the INNER JOIN command correctly?

Comment: Or, you know, that you are joining `PublishersID = ProductID` instead of `B.PublisherID = P.PublisherId`?

Comment: can you give an example of the data in each of the 2 tables? Does the current statement give an error? Does it just return the wrong thing?

Comment: Why are you aliasing Publishers as "PublisherID"?  It looks like you just need to really get your syntax straight.

Comment: the first word after a table name (as long as that word is not `as`) is interpreted by the engine as being an alias for that table.  So in your example you've aliased publishers as PublisherID and then tried to join the  table on an unknown object `publishersID` to column productID; now if productID exists in both tables then the dtaabase will not know which column from what table you meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.PublisherID, b.ProductID
FROM Books b
INNER JOIN Publishers p ON p.PublisherID = b.PublisherID
```

Comment: This is a correct join, but he'll still need to add some publisher-related fields to the select list to get "which books are associated with each publisher."

Comment: Updated query with more data.

Answer (score 0):

The ON part of a join defines how the two tables are related to each other.  In your case, it would be:

```
INNER JOIN Publishers ON (Books.PublisherID = Publishers.PublisherID)
```

If you put something between the name of the table, and the ON, it's treated as an alias.  You can (and should) also use these aliases in your SELECT

```
FROM Books B
INNER JOIN Publishers P ON (B.PublisherID = P.PublisherID)
```

Finally, you probably want to select information that will actually tell you who the publisher is:

```
SELECT B.ISBN, P.CompanyName    
FROM Books B
INNER JOIN Publishers P ON (B.PublisherID = P.PublisherID)
```